# Jhipster v2.20.0 : Static picture can't be loaded in production mode

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I deployed a **Jhipster** (v2.20.0) application in production mode. In an angularjs code i put :

```
img.src = assets/.../mypicture.png.
```

Locally this picture **il** loaded correctly, but in production mode I have the error :

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/assets/images/elements/teethschame/47.png] 

as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. 

If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Can you help me please, this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JHipster 2.x, the grunt/gulp build process minifies and adds a revision hash code to your images so that they can be cached forever by browser.

So, if you have an image in `assets/images/mypicture.png`, it will be available in  `dist/assets/images/mypicture-a1b2cde.png`. Then in prod profile, the `StaticResourcesProductionFilter` will prepend `/dist` to any request for an asset but it does not know about the revision code.

So, in your case either your code must refer to the versioned image name or you should exclude your images from being revisioned by moving them outside `assets` folder.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your response, but the problem was that i had to create a directory named :static, public or resource, in resourrces directory, and put my image directory in it to serve them in spring boot. This was indicated in the spring site : https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: Using resources is only one possibility, mine is also working.